# Registering an implicit broadcast receiver on boot completed (Android Oreo and above)

Tags: android

After receiving boot completed, I need to start a service on a different process **without notification**. This app targets API 28, which also targets devices with "Background Execution Limits". The specific use case will be this:

I need to catch the event that user opens the lock screen after locking it. There is a broadcast receiver I need to attach to the app, called "USER_PRESENT" which is triggered once the user is present (a.k.a opened the lock screen.) The current attach method is to start a service within the app, and register the receiver there. Then, once our operation is done, after 15 minutes, we need to do it again. (It can be at 16th minute, 17th minute etc... whenever it happens.)

After user opens our app, it works fine. However, as you know, we cannot start a background service after receiving "BOOT_COMPLETED" event. This is where the problem starts, because I cannot attach the broadcast receiver there, and I cannot start the service, hence the operation will not be performed.

From what I have read on [this link](https://medium.com/til-kotlin/jobintentservice-for-background-processing-on-android-o-39535460e060), it is possible to schedule a job using a [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService) and do your work there. But, it does not mention that I can attach a broadcast receiver, and, for our purpose to perform this operation, a job scheduler is not enough (because I need to detect it on spot after 15 minutes, can be at 16th minute or whatsoever, not when the work is performed), I need to attach that broadcast receiver to perform it, and I need to do it without posting a notification.

There is one dirty way I can think of, but it is not a good design and I don't want to use it, so I'm looking for a proper way: **Starting a transparent activity and calling startService there, then immediately closing it.** Other than that, I have no idea for now.

Could you please point me to the right direction to perform this operation? Thanks.

Comment: Your workaround will not be very effective. Your background service will be stopped after one minute, and after that, your broadcast receiver will go away once your process does.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this service runs on a different process. Editing the question.

Comment: AFAIK, that does not change the behavior of background services. Your background service will be stopped after one minute, and your broadcast receiver will go away once your different process does.

Comment: Okay, so how are services such as notification services are kept alive? For example, WhatsApp can immediately start its service (I'm not entirely sure it is a service but I'm assuming it) and catch notifications, while it runs without dying and without posting notifications.

Comment: I do not know what you consider "notification services" and  "catch notifications" to mean. In terms of messaging, WhatsApp presumably uses Firebase Cloud Messaging, at least on Google Play devices. This does not require a continuously-running service.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to start services without using FCM then?

Comment: Use a foreground service.

Comment: I meant without using a notification, which is required while running foreground services.

Comment: Work with a device manufacturer to add your functionality to the firmware. Or, create your own custom ROM that has your functionality.

Comment: Okay I see. It is impossible, then, in normal conditions.

Comment: I cannot rule out some security flaw. However, Google's plan is that either the user has to activate the service manually (e.g., `NotificationListenerService`), or the service has to have a `Notification` (foreground service), or the service cannot run for very long. The idea is that the user should have knowledge over what is running in the background for any significant length of time.

Comment: Alright. I might end up using a `JobIntentService` then, because none of the other ways are proper to achieve it above Oreo.

Comment: That too is not going to be completely effective. A job cannot run forever; neither can your process. When your process is gone, so is your dynamically-registered receiver. And, since jobs do not run in Doze mode, there is a distinct chance that the user will get through the keyguard before your job gets a chance to register a fresh receiver for the `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` broadcast.